# Using WSProxy to lookup rows returns "Error: Data extension does not exist:"

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

i'm using SSJS/WSProxy so that i can search data extension for a specific email address and return the DE name + any rows that contain that email.

I have the following FOR loop that takes each Email Address field in a DE and uses it along with the user-provided email to see if there are any records with the same email in a specific DE. However, while debugging the FOR loop, i noticed that the Retrieve Request using WSProxy says teh Data Extension doesn't exist - i've tried using both Data Extension Key and Name.

Can anyone tell me why i'm getting this result? FYI - i'm using WSProxy because 1. it's faster than SSJS Core library 2. This code should be able to return results from any and all BU's

**FOR Loop:**

```js
for (a = 0; a < dataExtensionFields.length; a++){
    if (dataExtensionFields[a].FieldType == "EmailAddress") {
        var emailField                  = dataExtensionFields[a].Name;
        var options                     = {BatchSize: 100};
        var props                       = { QueryAllAccounts: true };
        var cols                        = dataExtensionFieldNames
        var filter2                     = {
                                            Property        : emailField,
                                            SimpleOperator  : "equals", 
                                            Value           : email
                                        }
        var deObject                    = "DataExtensionObject[" + dataExtensionKey + "]"
        var recordsMatchingEmailInput   = prox.retrieve(deObject, cols, filter2, options, props);

        if (recordsMatchingEmailInput.Results != null) {
            dataExtensionsMatchingEmailInput.push(
                {
                    Name: dataExtensionName,
                    Records: recordsMatchingEmailInput
                }
            )
        };
    }; 
};
```

**Debugging Results:**

```
{"Status":"Error: Data extension does not exist: DEKEY","RequestID":"0099ebbe-776f-416a-b190-5af831068cbf","Results":null,"HasMoreRows":false}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `dataExtensionKey` is being filled correctly? If it is a shared DE, you can only access it from the BU that it was created in, regardless of share settings/permissions.

Comment: Yes - I verified that dataExtensionKey is being populated correctly

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington! Would you recommend using the SSJS Platform API functions then? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAPIFunctions.htm

Comment: Whoops these comments were in relation to another post (deleting them shortly). For this one, did you try doing it manually with a 'hard coded' name? Also is it a Shared DE?